# Prevent clicking to set a breakpoint in SQL Server Management Studio query text editor

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssms

When editing a stored procedure, I often want to click to the left of the line to select the entire line, or multiple lines. But the breakpoint column is the natural left margin of the window pane. So I often click to enable a breakpoint by mistake, then have to click it off, then carefully mouse to get the arrow cursor, then click to select the line.

Is there a way to disable clicking to set a breakpoint?

Barring that, is there a way to highlight the line selection column, with a background or border, similar to the breakpoint column? Then my eye would catch it, and I could train myself to mouse there.

I have sql server 2008 and sql server 2012, but this may apply to other versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** I think there is no way to remove the whole functionality.

But we can avoid this unwanted clicks on left window pane by enabling Line Numbers for code. To display line numbers SQL Server Management Studio will take some space to Break point edge. So that you will get less chance to make any unwanted break point.

To display line Numbers goto

> Tools -> Options -> Text Editors -> All Languages

[image: SSMS]

Comment: Yes, that works nicely. Without realizing it, that's how my Visual Studio with C# is set up, so these line numbers do give a good separation.